# von Neumann algebra generated by a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $A\subseteq B(H) $ be a $C^*$ algebra. I know that if $A$ is unital, then by von Neumann density theorem SOT closure$(A)=A''$ and $A''$ is the von Neumann algebra generated by $A$ in $B(H)$.

Is it true that if $A$ is not unital, still SOT closure $(A)=A ''$?

Comment: Yes if $A$ is non-degenerate.  For a counter example without this assumption, let $A$ be the operators on a 2-dimensional Hilbert space with matrix of the form $$\pmatrix{\lambda & 0 \cr 0 & 0}$$

Comment: Where Can I get a reference for this result?